# SOLVED How to display datatables by using id as the keyword data that is displayed (filter data from controller)

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.8

So I have Table A which has ['id', 'data', 'data']
Table B has ['id', 'id_A', 'data', 'data']
I want to display it in the datatable with the source of table B where the data displayed is based on id_A

data id send from controller Table A

```
    public function dataTable()
{
    $data = Kabupaten::query();
    return DataTables::of($data)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
        return view('layouts._action', [
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    })
    ->addColumn('kabkota', function ($data) {
        return '<a href="' . url('satuan',$data->id) .'">'.$data->kabkota.'</a>'; 
    })
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->rawColumns(['action','kabkota'])
    ->make(true);
}
```

my route

```
Route::resource('/kabupaten', 'KabupatenController');
Route::get('/data/kabupaten', 'KabupatenController@dataTable')->name('data.kabupaten');
Route::post('/kabupaten/import_excel', 'KabupatenController@import_excel');
Route::resource('/satuan', 'SatuanController');
Route::get('data/satuan', 'SatuanController@dataTable')->name('data.satuan');
Route::post('/satuan/import_excel', 'SatuanController@import_excel');
Route::get('/kab', 'HomeController@kabupaten');
Route::get('/sat/{id}', 'HomeController@satuanTable');
Route::get('/home/kab', 'HomeController@dataTable')->name('home.kab');
Route::get('/home/satuan/', 'HomeController@satuanTable')->name('home.satuan');
```

script

```js
<script>
  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {        
    columnDefs: [
    { width: 20, targets: [0]},
    { width: 90, targets: [6]},
    { width: 75, targets: [3,1]},
    { width: 125, targets: [2,5] },
    ],   
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: true,
    ordering: false,
    "ajax": "{{ route('home.satuan') }}",
    "columns": [
    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'id'},
    {data: 'npsn', name: 'npsn'},
    {data: 'nama', name: 'nama'},
    {data: 'jenis', name: 'jenis'},
    {data: 'alamat', name: 'alamat'},
    {data: 'kabkota', name: 'kabkota'},
    {data: 'capaian', name: 'capaian'},
    ]
});
</script>
```

trying to get id

```js
    public function satuanTable(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request();
        $data = Satuan::query()->where('id_kabkota', '=', $id);
        return DataTables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->rawColumns(['kabkota'])
        ->make(true);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this,, thankyou and im sorry for the language,

## Edit

i want displaying all data from table B , where id_fruit like id in TABLE A.

Like this
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Awcu.png)

Comment: What is the problem then ? in which column ? what do mean by "id as the keyword " ? Do you want to display id as well in your column or do you want to filter table based on the id ?

Comment: im edit the question sir

Comment: That's simple first create relation between table B and table A in the model, then use it in your query something like this `$tableB =  TableB::with('tableA_relation')->get()`

Comment: how i can get the parameter ID,  im send parameter to view, and how can controller api datatables get parameter ID, because if i send it to controller api datatable i just ge json data from table B, $table = TableB::query()->where('id_fruit', '=', $id) from last i use this query,, i got the data but just in API datatables, not in datatables view,, can u figure me how i can solve this,, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Send id to controller view

```
    ->addColumn('link', function ($data) {
        return '<a href="' . url('/sat',$data->id) .'">'.$data->data.'</a>'; 
    })
```

passing id to view

```
return view('guest.view')->with(['id_' => $id]);
```

Send back using ajax

```
"ajax":"{{ url('guest/data') }}" + '/' + "{{ $id }}",
```